# How can I tell if string contains both a Single-quote (') and a double-quote (")?

Tags: javascript

How can I check if string contains both a Single-quote (`'`) and a double-quote (`"`), like the one below?

```
var str = "test'\"";
```

Comment: Yet another example of responders on Stack Overflow being unnecessarily rude. There are people out there trying to learn how to program or speak limited English and being recommended to make use of Stack Overflow and this is the kind of treatment they get.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A quick way to check if the string contains both a single quote and a double quote.

```
if (str.indexOf('\'') >= 0 && str.indexOf('"') >= 0) {
   //do something
}
```

edit:  if the character is in the first position, indexOf will return zero.

Answer (score 6):

I'm guessing you want something like `/['||"]/.test(str);`

Comment: Note that he wants where a string contains *both* a single and double quote, not one or the other.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
var str = "test'\"";

if((str.indexOf('\'') > -1) && (str.indexOf('"') > -1))
{
    //Code here
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `IndexOf` is a typo, I guess: should be `indexOf`